# Bandpass filter to get EEG frequency bands?

Tags: fft, wavelet, bandpass, eeg

I'm doing a project with an EEG to detect driver drowsiness and learned about EEG frequency bands (alpha, beta, gamma...).

As the frequency bands are simple frequency ranges, I wonder if I can use several bandpass filters to get them (instead of using WPT / FFT)?

Is this approach correct? Is there any reason not to do it (performance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As the frequency bands are simple frequency ranges, I wonder if I can use several bandpass filters to get them (instead of using WPT / FFT)?

Sure! That's how it's usually done!

> Is there any reason not to do it (performance)?

*diabolical laugther* as it happens, I've prepared just the blog post for you… TL;DR: If you don't have to process more than 20 Million EEG samples per second, your PC should do fine performance-wise.

**[Filtering Time-Series Data](http://gnuradio.org/blog/filtering-time-series-data__elemental-building-blocks/)** on the GNU Radio blog.

I came across an [EEG problem](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28965/filtering-frequency-bands-out-of-a-signal) that tried to do exactly that, filter things into multiple bands. And lo, I had 5 minutes of fun designing this bandpass filterbank for signals  with $f_\text{sample}=220\,\text{Hz}$:

$$
\begin{align} 
\Delta:& [1,3]\text{ Hz}\\ 
\theta:& [4,7]\text{ Hz}\\ 
\alpha_1:& [8,9]\text{ Hz}\\ 
\alpha_2:& [10,12]\text{ Hz}\\ 
\beta_1:& [13,17]\text{ Hz}\\ 
\beta_2:& [18,30]\text{ Hz}\\ 
\gamma_1:& [31,40]\text{ Hz}\\ 
\gamma_2:& [41,50]\text{ Hz} 
\end{align}
$$

in this GNU Radio Companion flow graph

[image: Filterbank]

The result was that, even in this totally naive filterbank implementation, things are *so* much faster than real-time that you can assume that if done a little more cleverly, it'd work on any halfway DSP-affine microcontroller in real-time.

Comment: Extremely rapid prototyping :)

Comment: yeah, my first prototype actually was a single filter, and then I just went ahead and modified the Python script that GNU Radio companion generates to have a loop, which took the passband edges from an array and instantiated a filter for each of those – but then I realized that for the DSP.SE question I mention above, a graphical representation of what's happening would be much nicer :) But I'm slower at clicking than at writing `for` loops, so it's only semy-rapid prototyping ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - nice blog post! I just asked this, as most papers I've read used WPT / FFT to perform a frequency analysis. What does  `TransitionWidth` and `Beta` do?.

Comment: The transition width is a property of a filter response. It's the distance in frequency between the edge of the pass- end the beginning of the stop-band. (I.e. the width of the part of spectrum that is neither nicely let through by the filter, nor fully suppressed)

Comment: Beta is just a design parameter for a specific type of filter and not relevant here